# graphs and nodes in multicore systems

Tags: multiprocessing

What are *graphs and nodes* in a multi-core systems? Are they used in the parallel processing? What those terms mean and what is the role of them in parallel processing?

Answer (score 0):

Nodes usually refer to each individual computer.  There may be 2000 nodes in a huge hp computer.  All of the nodes end up making the parallel cluster computer.

Comment: @Eugeneokay and i came across the terms 'jobs from new graph invocation', and 'jobs from node readiness', what does these really mean? and what is the difference between these terms?